# GRU, I entered the time zone backwards, but the results are good. Can you tell me the exact input?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I want to design a system using GRU.
I recently found out that entered the time zone backwards.
My system has 256 time zones and 2 features using sliding window.

If you look at most examples, i saw input_shape=(256, 2) as input.
But what I first entered was input_shape = (2, 256).

for input_shape = (2, 256),
AUC: 97.7
Recall: 90.0
Get satisfactory performance with .

for input_shape = (256, 2);
AUC: 90.4
Recall: 89.6
It's not enough, but it's good performance.

The problem here is for input_shape = (256, 2):
gradient explosion occurs frequently and takes much longer to learn.
Both BatchNormalization and Min-Max Scaler have been applied.
If input_shape = (256, 2) is correct, is there an additional way to prevent a gradient explosion?

For input_shape = (2, 256), I was more satisfied with the performance and fast learning times. Can I do this?

Comment: Did you try to actually make predictions with the incorrect model? Also in the future questions like this belong on https://datasciencr.stackexchange.com or https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you, but the link you gave me is not valid....

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

No. Your incorrect but "good" model is predicting junk information on just 2 data points. None of your model performance metrics even make sense to compute. If you try to make predictions with that model, you will get a 256-length vector of junk.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. you says, i wiil get a 256-length vector of junk. but i can't understand.
for example, I organized the model like this.
def PAT_GRU():
    return Sequential([
        InputLayer(input_shape=(256, 2)),
        GRU(256, return_sequences=True),
        Dropout(0.5),
        GRU(128, return_sequences=True),
        Dropout(0.5),
        GRU(64, return_sequences=False),
        Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"),
    ])

Comment: Share your full code in the original question. I will delete my answer if it is incorrect.